# Autoplaying a movie in a PowerPoint presentation with C#

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint, office-automation

I am currently trying to change some settings in a .pptx files via C# and `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint`. I have some .wmv movies linked on several slides of the presentation. At the time the presentations were created, all movies play as soon as they are clicked. However, I want to change this to start automatically playing as soon as the slide is viewed. This this has to be done to a lot of presentations, so there is no way to do this manually.

I found the `PlaySettings.PlayOnEntry` property, but I can't figure out how to use it. I found several examples how to do this with a new movie to be embedded (and then, only for Visual Basic), but since the movies are already embedded, this is not what I want.

I also have no idea how I can actually access any objects on the current slide, maybe there is a way to check if a shape is a video-file and then change above setting, but the MSDN-Reference is not very helpful on Office-Topics. I'm using Powerpoint 2007 and Visual Studio 2010 if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. Searching through all shapes of the Presentation and filtering out the movies works:

```
//While iterating through all slides i:
   objShapes = objPres.Slides[i].Shapes;
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape s in objShapes) {
            if(s.Name.Contains(".wmv")){
            s.AnimationSettings.PlaySettings.PlayOnEntry = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
    }
   }
```

Comment: Great to hear it is sorted. You can accept your own answer by clicking the hollow checkmark next to the up/down arrows on this answer.  When you have a chance, take an opportunity to read through the FAQ @ http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Answer (score 2):

@Lennart's solution is part of it, you then need a page trigger

```
var videoAnimation = slide.TimeLine.MainSequence.FindFirstAnimationFor(objShapes);
if (videoAnimation != null)
{
    videoAnimation.Timing.TriggerType = PowerPoint.MsoAnimTriggerType.msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious;
}
```